# vim window split same color as background

Tags: vim, configuration, split

How can make my vim window split a different color?

**What I have:**
[image: have]

**What I want:**
[image: want]

On my MAC this wasn't a problem, but for some reason on linux the split bar is completely invisible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your current colorscheme to have whatever colors you want. A few tips:

- Find what colorscheme you are using by looking in your `~/.vimrc` or via `:colorschme`
- Horizontal split are separated by `StatusLine` highlight group and Vertical by `VertSplit`. See `:h highlight-groups`.
- May want to take a look at `'fillchars'` option. See `:h 'fillchars'`.
- There is a good [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode about this: [Creating colorschemes for Vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/)
- Go find a few colorscheme files to use as examples
- Use a tool like [Vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify/) to create your custom colorscheme

Comment: thanks a ton! It was totally just a colorscheme issue.